# How can I add up the columns?

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I want the total of the each column . There are no key values in my data that can be used as a group field for a "Group By Step".

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "Group By" step without providing a Group field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Group By" step without providing a Group field. Follow the below steps:

1. Select table input
2. Select "Group By" step

In Group by step follow the below steps:

Select what ever required grouping field and in looup field section assign function as sum/avg